# D Inline Assembler: Access Static Variable

Tags: assembly, d, inline-assembly

I got some trouble accessing a static Variable with Inline Assembler in the D Programming Language. The documentation says that I have to access local variables with

```
mov EAX, var[EBP]; //or mov EAX, var;
```

and class Variables with

```
mov EBX, this;
mov EAX, var[EBX];
```

But it isnt documented how to access a static Variable. Here is my code that throws an error:

```
module test;

static int A = 1234;

static void SetA()
{
    asm
    {
        mov A, 5432; //compiles, but throws an error
        //tried it with "mov dword ptr [A], 5432; too
    }
}
```

I really need a way of some "global storage" for integers that are accessible from both, assembler and D, I would be very happy about any help with this (or an alternative way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global variables are placed in thread-local storage by default in D2. Use `__gshared` to declare a "classic" static variable.

This works:

```
module test;

__gshared int A = 1234;

void SetA()
{
    asm
    {
        mov A, 5432;
    }
}

unittest
{
    SetA();
    assert(A == 5432);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: The `static` on `A` is redundant since it's a module-level variable. Same for module-level functions.

In D, module-level variables go into thread-local storage. You have to mark a variable as `__gshared` if you *really* want it to be global. Accessing TLS variables in inline assembly is basically not possible in a portable fashion.

One way to do what you want:

```
module test;

/*static*/ int A = 1234;

/*static*/ void SetA()
{
    int a;

    asm
    {
        mov a, 5432;
    }

    A = a;
}
```

Edit: If you intended `__gshared`, then see CyberShadow's answer. :)